# How to MBean depends EJBs in JBoss 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, mbeans

I'm using MBean in Jboss 7. Mbean need to call some EJBs at startup, but I cannot control ordering of startup EJBs and MBeans. In Jboss 4, I can do that by befine MBean in jboss-service.xml with depends tag. But in Jboss 7 this way does not work anymore.

```
<mbean code="com.mycompany.vms.adapter.connector.SourceConnector" name="mycompany:service=SourceConnector,source=SILTERRA" xmbean-dd="META-INF/SILTERRA-SourceConnector-xmbean.xml">
    <depends>jboss.j2ee:jndiName=mycompany/vms/ImportService,service=EJB</depends>
    <depends>jboss.j2ee:service=EJB,jndiName=mycompany/vms/EJBCommandService</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/ReceiverQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/DMuxerQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/ChannelProcessorQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/TransactionProcessorQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/SynchronizerQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/CommandQueue</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Topic,name=vms/SystemAlertsTopic</depends>
    <depends>jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=vms/LotIssueQueue</depends>
</mbean>
```

Please anyone help me on this. Anyway can do that on JBoss7?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275562/port-mbean-from-jboss-4-x-to-jboss-7)? It presents you solutions on how to migrate your MXBeans from JBoss 4.X to JBoss 7.

Comment: were you able to resolve this @duykaka ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your MBean into a `@Singleton` triggered `@Startup`, injecting on it its EJB dependencies.

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275562/port-mbean-from-jboss-4-x-to-jboss-7) and [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/singleton_the_simplest_possible_jmx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `jboss-ejb3.xml` file and list your enterprise beans in it to order the startup of your ejb's.

More details can be found here -
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/jboss-ejb3.xml+Reference